# How can I remove a parameter from the HttpContext.Request.Params collection?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, actionfilterattribute

How can I remove a parameter from the `HttpContext.Request.Params` collection?

I added it on the client as a form of "can't add a header to an iframe request" but now I want to remove it from the collection so it doesn't bother others sniffing the pipeline. I don't *have* to remove it, but I would like to.

I'm writing an ActionFilterAttribute and using the `OnActionExecuting` to test if it exists, so figured I would see if I could remove it as a matter of not polluting the pipeline any more than is necessary to send my request.

Comment: slightly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14130822/if-i-wanted-to-use-attributes-to-muck-about-with-an-mvc-return-contenttype-woul

Comment: @gdoron go on, try that, I'll wait here. Supposedly it's a read-only collection.

Comment: Read-only you say... Bad for you, bed for me. Good night!

Comment: The "Params" collection gets populated from the following collections once you touch it: QueryString, Form, Cookies, ServerVariables. So you would probably want to the value from the source collection to be consistent. If you do that before the Params collection is accessed, you would not need to delete the value from it.

Comment: I will try that tomorrow, thanks!

Comment: Looks like that doesn't work either Dmitry.